# Ubuntu Installer unable to find Hard Drive (HD is working, please read)

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, encryption, kali

I'm actually stuck since 3 days on this problem, after googling the last 60 hours about it i'm trying to ask here before loosing any faith.

I resume here the story to let you understand the situation completely.
I'm a linux ubuntu user since few years, i usually work with command line prompt and similar , so i'm not a "medium user", my skills goes behind this kind of user type.

So i was running Ubuntu on my system properly since a week ago when i decided to install Kali linux cause i wanted to try it. *I've installed Kali with full disk encryption* and after few days i decided to go back to Ubuntu (for various reasons).
So i made a bootable usb with Ubuntu 15 on it and tried to install as usual.
When it boot up i can continue on step 1 (language selection) and on second step i cannot proceed anymore cause the requirement of having more than 6gb of hd space isn't met. This is actually the main issue, since my hard drive is working fine. After few tries with Ubuntu installer I decided to nuke the hard drive with Boot and Nuke program which took around 9 hours to completely wipe out anything on the hard drive.
After the wipe the problem with hard drive requirements still persisted.
To verify the health of my hard drive i've decided to try it out with Windows 7 installation to find out if the problem could have been the hard drive itself.

*Windows 7 installation went fine and the Win installer recognised the hard drive instantly without any problem.*

**So the main issue is that Ubuntu installer cannot see my hard drive**, also if Win 7 installer does it.

I already googles many and many solutions around the web with no positive fix results. Here's a brief list of tries i did to fix this issue:

- Change SATA hardware cable on mainboard: no success.
- Change SATA mode in BIOS from IDE to AHCI mode: no success.
- Disable all the UEFI features in BIOS: no success.
- Boot Ubuntu in live mode and try install from live mode running: no success.

I tried also some other commands from terminal ( i cannot remeber those command now) but still no success.

I please you all to help me sort this out or i will go to permanently erase my hard drive with some acid.

Thank you.

StayCool.

Comment: Switch to console from the installation media (Alt-F2 usually), activate it and type: `fdisk -l`, paste the output here. Try `blkid`, but I am not sure if initramfs contains it. Also look on the kernel log (Alt-F4 I think) and look for sdX mentions and possible errors. That might help diagnose the problem.